# How to understand cause of G1 GC running for too long

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, garbage-collection

I'm trying to figure out cause of the GC running for 10-15 seconds at times. Most of the pause GCs are small but at times there's a sudden spike in pause GC time. I was trying to analyse GC logs.

```html
2023-06-08T05:32:10.709+0000: 593903.305: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young), 8.9649309 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 8963.5 ms, GC Workers: 4]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 593903305.3, Avg: 593903306.2, Max: 593903308.9, Diff: 3.6]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 2.4, Max: 3.3, Diff: 3.2, Sum: 9.6]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 5.3, Avg: 5.6, Max: 6.0, Diff: 0.7, Sum: 22.3]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 9, Avg: 62.8, Max: 84, Diff: 75, Sum: 251]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.0]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 8854.5, Avg: 8904.6, Max: 8954.6, Diff: 100.1, Sum: 35618.3]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 49.9, Max: 100.4, Diff: 100.4, Sum: 199.8]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 1.0, Max: 1, Diff: 0, Sum: 4]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 8959.9, Avg: 8962.5, Max: 8963.5, Diff: 3.6, Sum: 35850.2]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 593912268.7, Avg: 593912268.7, Max: 593912268.8, Diff: 0.1]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.0 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 0.1 ms]
   [Other: 1.3 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 0.5 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 0.1 ms]
   [Eden: 132.0M(132.0M)->0.0B(145.0M) Survivors: 21.0M->8192.0K Heap: 690.6M(3072.0M)->559.1M(3072.0M)]
 [Times: user=0.27 sys=0.01, real=8.97 secs] 
2023-06-08T05:32:19.674+0000: 593912.270: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 8.9664744 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0001051 seconds
```

I can see here that the real GC time is significantly higher than user and sys times, can anyone help me figure out what the problem might be?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with GC. The process didn't receive CPU time slice, presumably because of I/O or memory issues.

Comment: This is what I was suspecting as well. But looking at the logs, Object copy has taken most of the time that should mean that the problem is related to GC right?

Comment: No, it's a typical [survival bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias): GC activity is covered with stats and logs pretty well, while other operations are not. That said, GC may provoke the issue by doing memory intensive operations, but it's unlikely to be the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

###### 1. Check CPU usage

As you mentioned, real-time is very large. For this, try looking at CPU usage.

> Another situation to look out for is real time being a lot larger than the sum of the others this may indicate that the VM did not get enough CPU time on a possibly overloaded machine.

###### 2. Decrease -XX:G1NewSizePercent

Also, from the logs, we can see that the Object Copy is taking a lot of time.

> [Object Copy (ms): Min: 8854.5, Avg: 8904.6, Max: 8954.6, Diff: 100.1, Sum: 35618.3]

You can try the following options from [HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/garbage-first-garbage-collector-tuning.html#GUID-90E30ACA-8040-432E-B3A0-1E0440AB556A).

> If the Evacuate Collection Set phase takes too long, in particular, the Object Copy sub-phase, decrease -XX:G1NewSizePercent. This decreases the minimum size of the young generation, allowing for potentially shorter pauses.

###### 3. Adjust -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis

You can also specify the desired maximum pause time with `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis` .

> If you prefer high throughput, then relax the pause-time goal by using -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis or provide a larger heap. If latency is the main requirement, then modify the pause-time target.